# Concatenate large data frames horizontally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple (15) large data frames, where each data frame has two columns and is indexed by the date. All the data frames are approximately the same length and span the same date range. I would like to merge them horizontally (so no new rows are added). I tried `df_final = pd.concat(frames, axis = 1)` but this was extremely computationally ineffective and would not load. How else could I go about doing this? Screenshot of one of the constituent data frames attached

[image: dataframe example]
[image: what i'm want to do]

Comment: they are pretty large. maybe convert the ticker to categoricals, change dtype of atr to float32, and try again. pd.concat is a memory intensive operation though. I'd say convert to dict, merge the dicts and convert to a dataframe if all else fails. is there a final destination for the frames?

Answer (score 1):

If the data is aligned, you can try using the `ignore_index=True` parameter. This will skip the step of aligning the data. If the data is not aligned, I doubt you can increase much the speed…